How to make a responsive GridView() whose cell sizes change?
I want to create a responsive GridView() but just about everything I find discusses ways to do so that involve adjusting the number of cells in the grid's rows and columns. That's not what I'm trying to do; I'm using a SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount().
How do you make a GridView() widget that's responsive, with

a fixed arrangement of columns and rows. As the viewport width and height change, I want the cell sizes to change (rather than the arrangement of rows and columns), and
cells that appear square, i.e., the childAspectRatio is 1?

My code looks like this:
return GridView.builder(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 5,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4,
        childAspectRatio: 1,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          height: cellSize,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Tile(index: index),
        );
      },
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(36, 20, 36, 20),
      itemCount: 30,
    );

Tile() is a custom widget but it's a Container(). And cellSize does a MediaQuery.of(context) to figure out whether the view's height or width is smaller and select a size to fit.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and, in the end, simply replaced the GridView with rows and columns of Tile objects.

The default childAspectRatio is 1, you can change the item size from this.
   childAspectRatio: itemWidth/itemHeight,


Thanks for responding. I want the cells to be square, so the actual item width to height ratio should be one; I assume that's what childAspectRatio does. It's the actual width (and height) of the cells that would change, always maintaining the 1:1 ratio.

seems I am  missing something, can you checkout the Wrap widget, it is possible you are looking for that
